# Windows Server 2003 Enterprise - How Can I Add a SPF Record to DNS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, email, spf

I'm in the DNS management console, and I can't find SPF in the new record type list.

What do I need to do to create a SPF record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPF information is kept in DNS Text(TXT) type entries.  Right click the desired dns zone and select "Other New Record".  Scroll down in the subsequent window to the entry for "TEXT (TXT)".